# Moving from MySQL to MongoDB how to structure db

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

I'm building a simple test app with `Meteor` that allow users to search for the nearest restaurant, see the menu and order food. I've only really used MySQL and I'm not sure how's best to store the data. The structure I had in mind is:

```
restaurants: {
    untitledRestaurant: {
        name: "Untitled restaurant",
        menu: [
            starters: {
                name: "Starters"
                items: [
                    garlicBread: [
                        name: "Garlic bread",
                        price: 3.00
                    ],
                ]
            }
            mainCourses: {
                pizzas: "Pizzas"
                items: [
                    margherita: [
                        name: "Margherita",
                        price: 6.00
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ],
        branches: {
            regentStreet: {
                address: {
                    street: "1 Regent Street",
                    city: "Leeds",
                    county: "West Yorkshire"
                    postCode: "LS1234",
                    country: "UK",
                    coordinates: {
                        lat: 0.123456,
                        long: 0.123456
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

deliveryBoys: {
    andyWarhol: {
        name: "Andy WarHol",
        email: andy@warhol.io,
        mobile: 0123456789,
        address: {
            street: "2 Regent Street",
            city: "Leeds",
            county: ""West Yorkshire,
            postCode:LS1234 ,
            country: "UK",
            coordinates: {
                lat: 0.123456,
                long: 0.123456
            }
        },
        status: 0
    }

}

orders: {
    _id: {
        deliveryBoy: andyWarhol,
        restaurant: untitledRestaurant,
        branch: regentStreet,
        items: [{
            item: garlicBread
            amount: 2
        }, {
            item: margherita
            amount: 1
        }]
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have one collection of restaurants, their branches (with lat/long to do the "find nearest restaurant") and food items (divided by "types", e.g. starters, pizzas, desserts...).

Another collection is a list of delivery boys, because at every order I want to assign automatically the neared delivery boy available (this latter is read from status).

The final collection for the actual orders collection.

I'm not sure about a couple of things. First of all: what do you think of the structure? should I brake it to more collections or try to do it even with less?

Also how about ids? is it correctly that I define like the name (menu), and then the types (starters) and then the items? how would I better save their reference in the orders collection?

Also in terms of ids when I add restaurants or branches, or delivery boys... should is it fine that I define my own id?

Thank you for your time

Comment: This question calls mostly for opinion. Your schema seems to capture the basics of your problem but you won't really know until you start loading it with data from your app and querying it. For example you might find that it's easier to define a category for menu items instead of arranging them by *starter*, *mains* etc... That way if someone searches for *sweet potato pie* they can find it whether it's a dessert or a side. wrt *_ids* - let meteor set those for you, there's no point creating your own.

Comment: Right, I got `collection2` and `simple-schema` up and running and that's really helping me in figuring out how to build the db

Comment: Those are essential packages :)